# Autolayout issue with UIToolBar

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad, autolayout

I am new to auto layout and having a problem right away:)

this is my page in UIStoryboard
[image: Image in Storyboard with suggested Autolayout]

And this is the actual image on an iPad Mini Retina[image: image with actual layout on my iPad]

I really don't know why... I hope I find an answer here

Thanks for your time.

***Edit***

Here are the constrains of the ImageView
[image]

And of the ToolBar
[image]

Each priority is set to 1000

Comment: Can you show the auto layout constraints that are applied to the tool bar?

Comment: It looks like the image view you're rendering doesn't have a high enough priority on its height?

Comment: Its also possible that you need a fixed height constraint on your toolbar so it doesn't fill the space between the image, vertically.

Comment: Ok, I added the Constraints (I think...)

Comment: To find the constraints, select the tool bar and in the Utilities inspector, click on the Size Inspector icon (ruler) and the constraints that are added to the toolbar should display there. You added the possible constraints, and not the ones that are currently on it. =)

Comment: Ok, thanks for that tip:) I took a look on those settings, but I am not able to find anything , I added the settings to my question, can you take a look at it?

Comment: 1) try to set a fixed height constraint (44) for the toolbar ... or... 2) for the ToolBar try to set at 1000 Content Hugging ..

Comment: @DavidG. Are you hiding the Status Bar?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, no, I am not hiding the statusbar and btw, I had the problem with a Form Sheet, so there is no statusbar:) And you fixed the issue, setting the toolbars content hugging to 1000 did the trick. Thanks!